pip install to /usr/local
As we know from man hier, the /usr/local directory is reserved for users to avoid messing with /usr directly. The apt package manager does not touch anything under there:

$ dpkg -S /usr/local
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /usr/local


I.e. this namespace is specifically reserved for users' make install PREFIX=/usr/local and alike, allowing nice coexistence of apt-managed with sysadmin-managed software. (Also see /opt vs /usr/local.)

Notwithstanding the standards, python 3.12 is breaking the convention.
For example, I used to be able to build images with awscli preinstalled by simply:
pip install --prefix=/usr/local awscli

This no longer works† with python 3.12 onwards.

... Frankly, I couldn't care less about Python's evolution, ditching distutils (where I believe handling of --prefix=/usr/local used to be implemented), documentation removing even mere mentions of /usr/local installs (compare 3.10 VS 3.12), and so on. We don't get to overrule those upstream choices; they've already been made.
What I care about, is:

how to pip install stuff directly onto an OS (not into a venv sandbox);
such that it doesn't interfere with dpkg (/usr/local handles that perfectly for my needs);
such that installed libraries can be imported in python repl (of any user) out-of-the-box;
such that installed executables go to /usr/local/bin/ and are available immediately.

So far, the choices I see are:

pip install --break-system-packages --prefix=/usr/local foo bar

the --break-system-packages looks scary to peer review, despite making zero sense;


pip install --target=/usr/local/lib/python3.12/dist-packages/ foo bar

almost works as expected — doesn't link executables to /usr/local/bin.



Any other take?

Refs:

Debian advisory
Reddit discussion
SO discussion
PEP-668


† it ultimately demands the ominous flag --break-system-packages which looks scary but makes zero sense with semantics of the classic /usr/local prefix.

Please lose all the comments and if that is info for the question add it to the question. Comments are where you are asked for more info not where you add more info. I also do not see a clear help me with this question in this.

@DavidDE I linked related discussions that happen to mention the issues with /usr/local prefix. Also, this question is not exactly to get help; I'm capable of helping myself. I'm posing it to have a reference to point further discussions to.

Sorry that is not how this site works. You ask a question and you get an answer is how it works. This kind of this is just info post is best on a forum not a question and answer site.

"such that it doesn't interfere with dpkg (/usr/local handles that perfectly for my needs)" this is false. Pip-installed packages in /usr/local are known to break dpkg-installed Python programs when the /usr/local ones cause conflicting dependencies to get installed. There are hundreds (thousands?) of questions of the system breaking in various ways due to people doing this.

In fact, the frequent complaints from random users about random stuff breaking due to such mistaken assumptions about the filesystem hierarchy is pretty much what led to this change in the first place.

@muru I know that. When packaging up an entire system image — I also happen to know for a fact, that conflicts of that sort will not happen.

Sorry @DavidDE, but you should read https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

@ulidtko you might happen to know that for a fact for some specific set of software, not in general, even when packaging "an entire system image"

yes, and that's exactly what I have @muru. Even in less-specific cases, it's trivial to diagnose when things weirdly break with a mix of /usr and /usr/local stuff in tracebacks. I'm not saying, for everyone, but it is a simple failure-mode. So, /usr/local has served me well for many years. And I'm sure will do more

Sadly, being a simple failure mode doesn't help the vast majority of users who did face it, because it can affect a wide variety of packages in a wide variety of ways - GUI apps, especially, as random components start failing when they're loaded during runtime. You can do whatever you want, but do so on your systems, please don't post misleading information here

@muru I agree to disagree. Not trying to be misleading; but I do realize that the position I'm defending might be seen as controversial (due to vocal minority biases, strong at python community scale). My intent here is to gather & note down relevant notions, perhaps providing guidance for anyone searching for the same concerns. Future myself included; I'd went through this issue far not the 1st time.

Weirdly enough, on Debian and Devuan the --prefix needed to target /usr/local is /usr.
Meanwhile, --prefix=/usr/local installs to /usr/local/local/bin ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
This:
pip install --prefix=/usr awscli

produces the desired outcome, namely:

executable /usr/local/bin/aws,
python -c 'import botocore' working,
for all users of the container image.

Caveats
You'd best be sure you can guarantee the intersection of apt-installed and pip-installed python packages is, and will be, empty.
This is because both /usr and /usr/local form one "python installation"; the interpreter sees packages installed in both. (apt ones in /usr; pip ones in /usr/local).
Thus in PEP-668 terms, package shadowing may occur:

system tool foo depends on common == 1.*;
you pip-install bar that pulls in common >= 2.0;
system tool foo is now broken, because common v1 has been shadowed.


+1 for the caveats!

To summarize the generic advice pertaining to this issue.
1. Use apt package if possible
For simple needs, you might not actually need pip.
As an example, (some version of) requests can be installed with
sudo apt install python3-requests

2. Use venv, virtual environment
It's rather simple to spin up a dedicated "python installation" a.k.a. venv with completely isolated set of packages.
sudo apt install python3-venv

python3 -m venv my-shiny-awesome-sandbox
source my-shiny-awesome-sandbox/bin/activate

pip list #-- empty
pip install ....

Then you don't have to worry about interactions with system packages.
Instead, you worry about maintaining & activating the venv.
3. Use pipx
sudo apt install pipx
pipx run pycowsay moo

This conceptually maintains an implicit hidden venv.
Because pipx is oriented at apps (console_scripts entry points), it's not trivial to install libraries with it, that you could use in your own scripts.
4. Say --break-system-packages
sudo pip install --break-system-packages awscli

This will install to /usr/local. You'll get both the entrypoint scripts, and the libraries.
A caveat is, you run the risk of intermixing apt packages with pip ones, if not careful. That's why the option name is intentionally scary.

pip install --user can be also "repaired" with:
dpkg-divert --rename --add /usr/lib/python3.12/EXTERNALLY-MANAGED

— as explained in /usr/share/doc/python3.12/README.venv.
